# Good books on Kievan Rus era?

Tags: russia, book, ukraine

Title pretty much self explenatory.

Im a student myself (but not of history), and I am looking for a good book on the period that is not too heavy, but gives good coverage for early east Slavic history, Kievan Rus period etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Source requests are explicitly [off-topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, so I suspect that your question may be closed.  You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Such requests are currently off-topic. A modern book on this subject that I happen to like is "The Emergence of Rus 750-1200." by Simon Franklin.

Comment: To quickly summarize, the problem is that "good" is a subjective word.  What I think is a good history may be completely useless to someone else, and actively wrong to a third person.  Such questions make it impossible to select an authoritative answer, and generally fall into the category of [shopping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/259135) questions.  Many of us would like to see a way to permit reference questions, but it is a problem we haven't solved just yet.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: I wonder why "off topic" and especially why "currently". Can you explain? Is this because of the ongoing war between Russia and Ukraine?

Comment: @Alex: No, all "general" reference requests are currently off-topic in HSE (although, the matter is currently under discussion, again); for instance a reference request to the history of England  was recently closed for this exact reason (and it has nothing to do with the polonium poisoning of Litvinenko): https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/59703/what-is-a-good-book-about-the-history-of-england#comment181316_59703

Comment: @Alex What constitutes "a good book" on any given subject is generally likely to be a matter of opinion.  If the answers are likely to be primarily opinion based, then, per our Help Centre, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Of course a book recommendation is always a matter of opinion. Do you think that book recommendations in general must be excluded on this site?? This is frequently asked and answered.

Comment: @Alex According to our Help Centre, [reference requests are explicitly off-topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and have been since long before I joined the site.  This is a frequently discussed topic on meta, with the [latest discussion](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/requests-for-references) having started just 2 days ago.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: If this is so, the tags "book" and "reference" should be removed.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps, although if you followed the links on the current meta discussion you'll have seen that [requests for canonical sources](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/may-i-request-canonical-resources/3827#3827) are an exception to the general rule.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: What is the definition of "canonical source"? Who decides which sources are canonical?

Comment: @Alex As stated in the linked meta post: "*references that almost all scholars in the field would point to*"

Comment: @semipaiscuba: such consensus does not necessarily exists in every filed. Do we ban references and books in the field where there is no consensus? This question btw is an example of such a field, where there is no consensus.

Comment: Without prejudice to the OP who was probably unaware of this debate, are we in agreement that a fairly simple rearrangement (or a 'kinder reading') of the question would result in "What are canonical resources on Kievan Rus?" which would be already allowed—so the primary problem is in the present wording of the question?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the languages you can read. The best book that I know is in Russian:

> Alexei Tolochko, Essays on the original Rus,
>
> Толочко А. П.
>   Очерки начальной руси. Киев; Санкт-Петербург,
>   Лаурус, 2015.

And in Ukrainian:

> Наталья Николаевна Яковенко, Нарис Історії України. З найдавніших часів до кінця XVIII століття (Essay of the history of Ukraine from the ancient times to XVIII century).

One problem with the history of Kievan Rus, is that this subject is highly politically charged. This "history" was originally created with a political purpose:
to confirm the rights of the ruling dynasty. Then in 17-18 centuries, the Moscow state "appropriated" this history, and even the name Rus, and since then, the "history" was used mostly to prove the right of Moscow to rule the territory which used to be Kievan Rus.

This did not change to this day. For this reason I do NOT recommend reading only Russian (Moscow)
authors. In the writings of Ukrainian authors the point of view is very different,
though some Ukrainian authors may be biased in another direction.
(The author that I recommend is least biased on my opinion: he lives and works in Ukraine, but writes in Russian. Not to be confused with his father, P. Tolochko).

Speaking of Western authors, I can recommend

> [Orest Subtelny, Ukraine: A history](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1442609915)

whose initial chapters are on Kievan Rus.

When searching for Western authors, I recommend to search on "History of Ukraine", rather than "History of Russia", unless you want to read the Moscow propaganda retold by a Western author.

Another problem is almost complete lack of original sources. The main source is the so-called "Original chronic", which was written centuries after the events it describes, and also under the sponsorship of the ruling dynasty. Foreign sources are
extremely scarce.

Having all this in mind, you can certainly read this original chronic, or any modern exposition of it.

Remark: the more correct tag for this question is "history of Ukraine" not "history of Russia". (Kiev is in Ukraine, as we all know). So I added the tag.